# admob video interstitial adds are not displayed full screen in android

Tags: android, admob

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6LxXqtbrL0PY2JSaTdva0RaRGJ4d092Y01IVmVnSmhQa3E4/view?usp=sharing[image]

I am displaying admob's video add in my app but some ads comes only in half screen I have searched and tried a lot and i i am loading this interstitial properly but some video ads displays in half screen only not all time but some times

Comment: They are ads of that size only. Remaining is in black color. They are full screen ads only.

Comment: but close button is displayed in middle of the screen